# How can I load and use torch deep learning models from python?

Tags: python-2.7, lua, deep-learning, torch

I use python for my real application and like to harness a torch model in python. Is there any available interface or a tenuous way to do so ?

Answer (score 5):

There are several libraries enables you to interact with torch in python, but I would recommend **lutorpy**, here are some details:

- [**lutorpy**](https://github.com/imodpasteur/lutorpy): the most promising one for deep learning with torch, it's based on lupa, easier to use(more pythonic). It keeps a lua engine in python, all lua variables and functions are automatically converted into python objects. So, you can import any torch module by using "require" function. 
  You can easily convert almost any lua/torch code into python with very minimal change. It also provide conversion functions for numpy array and torch tensor,n the conversion is instant because they share the underlying memory.
- lunatic-python:
  a minimal library for using lua in python, but the features are limited
- [lupa](https://github.com/scoder/lupa):
  a library for using lua in python with a lot of useful features, but it's for lua in general, not torch, for example you can't easily convert torch tensor into numpy array.
- pytorch:
  a wrapper for torch, the code are taken from torch and compiled into python module, so you can use torch pythonicly, but the module you can use is very limited (only nn are supported so far).

Here is one example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36896347/6262499

Comment: pytorch author here.  You can import your own lua classes now.  See for example https://github.com/hughperkins/pytorch-residual-networks or https://github.com/hughperkins/cifar.pytorch

Comment: @HughPerkins That'd be great, but how do I import lua/torch classes into pytorch? The links point to pytorch implementation of a NN, they don't seem to show how to import a lua class. What am I missing? Tnx!

Comment: Nuance: this question is very old. The pytorch mentioned here is not the pytorch that Adam and Soumith et al created recently. I reckon using the newer Facebook-provided pytorch is a good way forward, and then I reckon you might check on eg https://discuss.pytorch.org for answer(s) to your own root requirements/use-cases perhaps?